# Array.from(Object).forEach not working with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I create object like this on my data() in vue.js 2 CLI:

```
data(){
    return{
        user: {
            user_mail: '',
            user_password: '',
            user_confirm_password : '',
            user_phone : '',
            user_fname: '',
            user_lname: '',
        },
    }
},
```

Now I'm trying to print this object on a the log useing mounted function:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.user)
},
```

It works fine.
The problem starts when I trying to go through it with forEach:

```
mounted() {
    Array.from(this.user).forEach((value) => {
        console.log(value)
    });
},
```

In this situation I don't get any output on my log.
Any suggestions?
Thanks :)

Comment: I would assumed mounted isn’t firing for some reason.  Do you have the Vue browser extension?

Comment: `Array.from()` doesn't work with ordinary objects, only array-like objects. What are you expecting `Array.from(this.user)` to return?

Comment: @Barmar - you’d expect an error if that were the cause, no?

Comment: @dgo You might, but it just returns an empty array in that case.

Comment: @dgo no, it is perfctly fine to use it on array-like objects, like this: Array.from({'0': 'A', '1': 'B', length: 2})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array from creates an array from an iterable, which does not work on plain objects.

> The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

You could use `Object.values`, `Object.entries` or `Object.keys`

```js
Object.values(this.user).forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.from()` cannot create an array from your object. Instead of it, you could just use *the old simple way*:

```
for (const key in this.user) {
  console.log(this.user[key]);
}
```